# Testcontainer not able to start within PCF CI/CD Jenkins pipeline - container-inside-container problem?

Tags: java, docker, junit, jenkins-pipeline, testcontainers

I've been trying to use the Testcontainers library with my current Jenkins CI/CD pipeline for postgres DB integration tests. I was previously using an embedded postgres library, but now in my jenkins pipeline I do all the steps inside a container, and I wasn't able to make it work. Then I came across the Testcontainers project which seems to be a pretty good alternative for my Java Spring project.

I've been following this [article](https://jschmitz.dev/posts/testcontainers_how_to_use_them_in_your_spring_boot_integration_tests/) and it states that we most likely don't have to change anything for CI environmets because testcontainers recognizes that it's running inside a container and it supports it. Also, in testcontainer's official documentation there's [this](https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/dind_patterns/).

So, apparently it's supposed to work even if we are running the integration tests within a containerized environment, but when I try it I get the following error in my integration tests:
`ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration.`

This is my jenkinsfile (I use PCF)

```
node('pcf-node') {
        container('jdk17-container') {
            ...
            stage('integration testing') {
                currentStep = "${env.STAGE_NAME}"
                runIntegrationTests()
            }
        ...
    }
}
```

After some research I'm still not sure if docker should be accessible within the container from the jenkins pipeline, but when I run `docker info` inside de container it returns `docker: command not found`.

Any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: have you mount the socket from host in your container as mentioned https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/dind_patterns/#docker-only-example?

Comment: I think you need docker in docker support on your Jenkins machine

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the machine on which Jenkins is installed is also running the Docker process?

In order to use test-containers, Docker must be installed and running on the machine on which you are running the tests.
The solution is to install and run the Docker process on the CI/CD machine.

For example: try turning off your local instance of Docker and launching testcontainers tests. You will get something like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration

    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$6(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:242)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:234)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:135)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:176)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory$1.getDockerClient(DockerClientFactory.java:90)
    at com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClientDelegate.authConfig(DockerClientDelegate.java:108)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:325)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.start(TestcontainersExtension.java:242)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.access$200(TestcontainersExtension.java:229)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$null$1(TestcontainersExtension.java:59)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$4(ExtensionValuesStore.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.computeValue(ExtensionValuesStore.java:223)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:211)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.evaluate(ExtensionValuesStore.java:191)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.access$100(ExtensionValuesStore.java:171)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:89)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:53)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$beforeAll$2(TestcontainersExtension.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.beforeAll(TestcontainersExtension.java:59)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:381)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:381)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:205)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Answer (score 0):

It Seems like , where test code is running docker service is not running on the same machine so this issue is occurred.